# Magento 2 getChildHtml

Tags: magento, magento2, magento-2.0

Trying to include custom.phtml file in to header. Searched many instructions, but didn't see any like `getChildHtml`
For .xml I found

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="test_file" template="Magento_Theme::html/header/custom.phtml"/>
```

For .phtml I found

```
<?php include ($block->getTemplateFile('Magento_Theme::html/header/custom.phtml')) ?>
```

That means that, for adding .phtml file we can use .xml or .phtml, but not as we are accustomed: add templates to the .xml and after that call this file from .phtml  (getChildHtml)

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```html
<referenceContainer name="header.container">
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="test_file" template="Magento_Theme::html/header/custom.phtml"/>
</referenceContainer>
```